# What additional properties does a finite $k$-partite graph have if the endpoints of every edge have a common neighbor in each independent set?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory, extremal-graph-theory

I've been working through a proof for a while now, and I've come across this class of graphs as the output of the algorithm I'm analyzing, however, I've managed to get absolutely nowhere proving any additional properties about them.

If you have a finite $k$-partite graph $G$, where the endpoints of each edge share a neighbor in each of the remaining independent sets, are there any other interesting properties which $G$ might have i.e. chordal, perfect...?

I'd really really appreciate any and all help on this!

Edit: The maximum cardinality of each independent set is 3 and the ultimate goal is to prove that if $G$ has this global edge property, then $G$ is guaranteed to have at least 1 $k$-clique (or that finding the clique-number of $G$ has polynomial time complexity)

<s>Edit 2: I've posted this question here on Reddit with a description of the mentioned algorithm</s>

Comment: Would an example of such a $G$ without a $k$-clique answer your question?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yep, that'd be super helpful! Though I'd still like to know if $G$ might have any additional properties if you might have any insights on that as well?

Comment: Unfortunately, all I saw right away is the counterexample to the first conjecture. In particular, I don't have any ideas on the time complexity of finding the clique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conjecture that every such graph contains a $k$-clique is false.

To see this, consider (for $k\ge 4$) a $k$-partite graph in which the $i^{\text{th}}$ part contains $3$ vertices $v_{i,1}, v_{i,2}, \dots, v_{i,3}$, and in which two vertices $v_{i,j}$ and $v_{i',j'}$ are adjacent whenever $i \ne i'$ and $j \ne j'$.

In other words, the tensor product $K_k \times K_{3}$.

For example, here is the $k=4$ case of such a graph:

[image]

In this graph, two vertices $v_{i,j}$ and $v_{i',j'}$ in different parts, whether or not they're adjacent, have a common neighbor in each other part. The $i''^{\text{th}}$ part contains a vertex $v_{i'',j}$ not adjacent to $v_{i,j}$, and a vertex $v_{i'',j'}$ not adjacent to $v_{i',j'}$, but the third vertex in that part is adjacent to both.

However, for $k\ge 4$, there is no $k$-clique in this graph - not even a $4$-clique - because if we take any $4$ vertices from this graph, two of them will agree on their second index by the pigeonhole principle. Then there's no edge between them.

Comment: Thank you so much for providing a counter-example! Do you know if a similar method could be used if each independent set was restricted to three vertices no matter what the value of $k$ was? This here perfectly shows when $k$ = 4 the answer is no, but does it generalize to any $k$?

Comment: In fact, this construction appears to work with no modification if we make every independent set have $3$ vertices. I've edited my answer to that construction, because it seems nicer.

Comment: Ah I see, last question, do you know if this construction characterizes the graphs which have the property I'm looking for, but do not have a $k$ clique, or might there be another construction which creates a graph that could serve as a counter-example but isn't isomorphic to yours?

Comment: Without the restriction that every part have $3$ vertices, there should be lots and lots of examples. With that restriction, we can still start with this construction and keep adding edges arbitrarily for as long as there's no $k$-clique, but it's possible that's the only thing we can do. (But I don't have a proof of that.)